# google-api: Request had invalid authentication credentials OAuth 2?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

from this docs : `https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account`

i do it by using nodejs by folow these step

- create a new service account, and got an email.
- call `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` to get an access token and then i got the `id_token`.
- i put the `id_token` to headers like `Authorization: Bearer ${id_token}`.
- but when i called the `https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/get` , i have got an error like this :
  {
  error: {
  code: 401,
  message: 'Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.'](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%27),
  errors: [ [Object] ],
  status: 'UNAUTHENTICATED'
  }
  }

- am i do anything wrong? ,please give me some advice.

i just want to get an status of an in-app purchase from my server.